# How To Get Subtitle/Promotional Text From iTunes Search API

Tags: ios, api, app-store, itunes-store, itunes-search-api

Currently I can get the app title, description and other details such as developer name, app ID, category etc. from the iTunes Search API but cannot find out how to get the Subtitle or Promo Text despite them being released on the App Store over a year ago.

Displaying the full results mentions nothing about subtitles or promo text.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Looking for this too.  Did you ever figure it out?